# what is the difference between ( )=>React.FC and ( )=>JSX.Element

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In React, it seems that I can declare a functional component or just a function returns a JSX element.
What confusing me is I don't know the key difference between these two approaches.
Is there anything only one approach can do while another can not?

```
import React from "react";

type ItemProps = {
    id: number
    name: string
}

const Item: React.FC<ItemProps> = ({ id, name }) =>
    (
        <section>
            my id is {id}
            my name is {name}
        </section>
    )

const item = ({ id, name }: ItemProps) =>
    (
        <section>
            my id is {id}
            my name is {name}
        </section>
    )

export const Container = () =>
    (
        <section>
            {item({ id: 1, name: "item-1" })}
            <Item id={1} name={"item-1"} />
        </section>
    )
```

Answer (score 25):

## Summarising the differences:

### React.FC:

- has an implicit `children` prop, which means even if your component does not allow children, typescript would not complain if you are using `React.FC` and the parent passes a children. This does not impact anything at the runtime, but it is better to be more explicit about the children prop. This might be going away in the next version of `React.FC`, even now you can use `React.VFC`
- does not work well with defaultProps
- does not allow generics
- can't be used to annotate a function declaration, only function expressions
- makes "component as a namespace" pattern difficult to type

### JSX.element + props interface

- does not have an implicit children prop, so you need to declare it explicitly, which is good, and some people prefer implicit return type anyway. This does not have default support for other/static properties like `propTypes`, `displayName` etc, so they would need to be added explicitly if required.
- does not care about default props, this is just regular function typing for arguments and return types
- can be used with generics
- can be used to annotate a function declaration as well as expressions

### Resources

- https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components/
- https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react-why-i-dont-use-react-fc/
- https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177

Comment: as of today the FC type does not have implicit children props because in [v18](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/81311713a72ce3c394551de736059b9e6b696a32/types/react/index.d.ts#L520) of react types the props are no longer defined as propsWithChildren.

Answer (score 6):

`React.FC` offers Type checking support

*You can also write components with React.FunctionComponent (or the shorthand React.FC - they are the same):*

```
const App: React.FunctionComponent<{ message: string }> = ({ message }) => (
  <div>{message}</div>
);
```

***Some differences from the "normal function" version:***

- React.FunctionComponent is explicit about the return type, while the
  normal function version is implicit (or else needs additional
  annotation).
- It provides typechecking and autocomplete for static properties like
  displayName, propTypes, and defaultProps.

  - Note that there are some known issues using defaultProps with
    React.FunctionComponent. See this issue for details. We maintain a
    separate defaultProps section you can also look up.
- It provides an implicit definition of children

Checkout docs for more information

https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react/blob/main/README.md#section-2-getting-started

Answer (score 4):

In React, the return of a function is `JSX.Element`. Even the return of the declaration in `React.FC` must be `JSX.Element`

If you have implicit return:

```
const Component: React.FC = () => {}
```

If you have explicit return

```
const Component = (): JSX.Element => {}
```

Comment: you can tell it's still early for me, you made me google `chipden` :facepalm:

Answer (score -3):

difference between these two approaches are documented [here.](https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet/blob/master/README.md#basic-cheatsheet-table-of-contents)

> provides type checking and auto complete,

Comment: This is _almost_ the answer I'm looking for. Unfortunately, the link seems to have changed so that section you referenced isn't so helpful. Furthermore, your answer doesn't specify which option provides type checking and auto complete. This leaves me as confused as I was at the start.

Comment: Dinesh, you should probably inline some more of the important bits from the link into this answer