# Where to put generit type T declaration in React FC type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a React component with some generic properties and would like to type them using a generic type T. But I can't figure out where to put the T declaration.

Here's my component signature:

```
interface MyComponentProps<T> {
  items: T
}

// ------------------------------------------v cannot find name T
const MyComponent: React.FC<MyComponentProps<T>> = ({
  items
}) => {
  // ...
}
```

Where can I put `<T>` to satisfy the generic type declaration?

Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656026/what-is-the-difference-between-react-fc-and-jsx-element) will also probably be useful. Basically: There's really no good reason to use `React.FC` at all. :-)

Comment: This does not answer the generic part of the question.