# Different ways to define React function components

Tags: reactjs

In React v18 and TypeScript v5.1 and later are there any significant differences between those two ways of defining the React function component?

```js
const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent = () => <div></div>
const MyComponent2 = (): React.JSX.Element => <div></div>
const MyComponent3 = () => <div></div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58656026/what-is-the-difference-between-react-fc-and-jsx-element

Answer (score 1):

Key Differences:

- Explicit Type vs. Inference: MyComponent is explicitly typed as a React.FunctionComponent, while MyComponent2 and MyComponent3 rely on TypeScript's type inference.
- Default children Prop: Only React.FunctionComponent includes the children prop by default.
- Flexibility: The third approach (MyComponent3) offers the most flexibility and is succinct, which is why it's popular in many React projects.

Best Practice:

The choice among these depends on your project's needs and coding style preferences. If you prefer explicit types and might use React-specific static properties, go with React.FunctionComponent. If you prefer succinctness and rely on TypeScript's type inference, you might choose the second or third option.

Comment: does React.FunctionComponent still includes children prop by default in newer versions of react and ts?

Comment: My mistake. In the previous version the children prop was already defined as an optional property in React.FC type. In the recent version, this has been removed. Now, you have to specify it explicitly depending on your need. It can be either optional or required, it’s up to your own logic. You can override react types by creating a custom type definition file if you need it.